# How can I place animations over a static image in HTML/CSS code?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a static image on a webpage (which is a picture of some text, would like to keep the integrity of this document) and overlay animations on top of the image, such as a box that will hover over a block of text (from the static image) and provide additional context into the block of text. I have used hover for CSS but am looking for other solutions, since when I zoom the page the box over the block of text does not line up with each other. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your main problem is the positioning of your animations/highlights, then the way to fix that is to position them using percentage (not pixel) values relative to your image.

In the snippet below, I enclosed an image with some text in a `<div>` set to width 50% (so it will resize if you resize your browser window). The image fills the whole div, and an absolutely positioned text highlight is positioned using percentages over the image.

When you resize the window (or tweak the width css of the containing div), the image will change size, but the highlight should still be positioned over the text correctly. Hover over the image to view.

```css
.imageholder {
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}

img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.highlightrect {
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    height: 28%;
    left: 26%;
    width: 44%;
    border: 3px solid orange;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.imageholder:hover .highlightrect {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageholder">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
    <div class="highlightrect"></div>
</div>
```